# How can I change the image memory on OpenStack?

Tags: openstack

I'm playing around with the OpenStack API.  Is there a way to change the minimum memory required by an image?  I initially created an image with 4GB RAM, but now I need to launch that image with only 2GB RAM.  Since Linux supports changing the amount of available RAM (after a reboot), I'm assuming there must be a way to reduce the minimum RAM required by an OpenStack image.

Note: When I try to launch the image with a 2GB flavor, I get the following message:

```
Error: Unable to launch instance: Instance type's memory is too small 
for requested image. (HTTP 400)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can there is an API for that.

```
# First list all images to note down the uuid of image you want to change
glance index

# Check how to use the image update function
glance help image-update
# or if you dont know which function to use just run
glance help

# The following command will change minimum ram to 2000MB and minimum disk to 1GB
glance image-update <<uuid or name of image>> --min-ram 2000 --min-disk 1
```

Comment: Note: the correct syntax (at least for 2012.1-3-dev) is:
`glance update <<uuid>> min_ram=X min_disk=Y`